# SHIPPINGOPTION values missing in response to GetExpressCheckoutDetails call to PayPal NVP API

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using PayPal Express with the NVP API and the response from the GetExpressCheckoutDetails call is missing all the SHIPPINGOPTION values, the customer can pick a shipping option on PayPal's side but PayPal don't return it.

When I was debugging the issue that this is causing on our site (resting the customers shipping to default) I discovered that our test site pointing at the sandbox is working fine (although I get the old style UI) and it is correctly returning the SHIPPINGOPTION values in the response.

Both the live and test site are running the same PHP code, and the sites integration settings for PayPal are the same apart from the credentials and live/sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, in my case it turned out to be an issue on PayPal's side. I had to contact Merchant Technical Support and they fixed it.